# elements that I anchor with anchors in a cell are not displayed. How fix it?

Tags: ios, swift

I am developing an application, and I need to add a label and an image to the cell, I did this with this code

```
class CustomGroupCell: UITableViewCell {

var cellTitle = UILabel()
var imageViewContainerForShadow = UIView()
var imageViewForCell = UIImageView()

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    contentView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    contentView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 245).isActive = true
    contentView.addSubview(cellTitle)
    contentView.addSubview(imageViewContainerForShadow)
    imageViewContainerForShadow.addSubview(imageViewForCell)

    setupCellTitle()
    setupImageViewContainer()
    setupImageForCell()
}

private func setupCellTitle() {
    cellTitle.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leadingAnchor, constant: 44).isActive = true
    cellTitle.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.topAnchor, constant: -4).isActive = true
    cellTitle.trailingAnchor.constraint(lessThanOrEqualTo: contentView.trailingAnchor, constant: -163).isActive = true
}

private func setupImageViewContainer() {
    imageViewContainerForShadow.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cellTitle.bottomAnchor, constant: -10).isActive = true
    imageViewContainerForShadow.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.bottomAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
    imageViewContainerForShadow.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.leftAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
    imageViewContainerForShadow.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: contentView.rightAnchor, constant: -20).isActive = true
    imageViewContainerForShadow.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: imageViewContainerForShadow.heightAnchor, multiplier: 373.0/199.0).isActive = true

}

private func setupImageForCell() {
    imageViewForCell.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: imageViewContainerForShadow.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
    imageViewForCell.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: imageViewContainerForShadow.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
    imageViewForCell.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: imageViewContainerForShadow.topAnchor).isActive = true
    imageViewForCell.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: imageViewContainerForShadow.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
}
```

also

```
class RecipesViewController: UITableViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    tableView.register(CustomGroupCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "customGroupCell")

    view.backgroundColor = UIColor(named: "AppBackgroundColor")
}

override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 2
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "customGroupCell", for: indexPath) as! CustomGroupCell

    cell.cellTitle.text = "TESTING"
    cell.imageViewForCell.backgroundColor = .blue

    return cell
}
```

}

But when I run the simulator, nothing happens and all the cells are black, without any size changes (They should be)

[problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ifZRi.jpg)

Changes to the cell configuration (class "CustomGroupCell" do not change the result. Maybe I missed something? I think problem in RecipesViewController.

Comment: If set background color for cell in "cellForRowAt" then background has changed, but also anchors don't work

Comment: Do you have any Constraint error in your XCode console? if yes this could help solve you problem

Answer (score 0):

the problem is solved using `layoutSubviews()` instead `awakeFromNib()`

Answer (score -1):

To set the height of your cells, don't set contentView's height, but rather use the following tableView function:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return 245
}
```

Comment: Well, the cell height has changed, but the problem is not solved, the cells are still black